# Cómo coloco mi código debajo del título de un post en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estoy haciendo un plugin para poner mi código debajo de los títulos en los artículos de Wordpress. No sé como hacerlo, tengo un código hecho, pero aparece al lado del título (no debajo) como puedo ponerlo debajo?

Esto es lo que tengo de mi código:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'diww_pre_content' ); //Add a filter to 'the_content' to hook ad_content() function
```

function diww_pre_content($title)
{
            if (is_single()) //Solo aplica si es un post.
            {
                $custom_title = 'ADSENSE';

```
$title = $title . $custom_title; //el codigo de adsense va debajo del titulo

return $title;
```

}else{
        //para lo que no sea un post, muestra lo regular.
        return $title;
}
}
?>

Como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

No me queda muy claro, pero seguramente sea un tema que se puede solucionar con css o simplemente con un `<br/>` :

```
$title = $title .  "<br/>" . $custom_title;
```

o usando clases de bootstrap 4:

```
$title = $title .  '<span class="d-block">' . $custom_title . '</span>';
```